# Writing to a Static Text Box in a Panel - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, static, panel, children, matlab-guide

I created a matlab GUI using GUIDE.

I created several panels with static text boxes inside them. I would like to write values to all the boxes once I push an "update" pushbutton.

for instance, I would like to write to a box with tag AV1, and the text box is inside panel "uipanel2".

Both ways give errors:

`set(handles.AV1,'String','hi');`
The above code does not work as it says the field does not exist. This makes sense as I need to access the panel first.

So below I access the panel, but how do I get to its children?

`set(handles.uipanel2.AV1,'String','hi');`

this code gives the following error: *Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.*

Comment: and just displaying handles.uipanel2 gives 242.0026 in the console :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Children` is a field so if you want the children you can try `get(handles.uipanel2,'Children')` and it will give you an array with handles to the children. It will look like numbers to you in the same way that the handle to `uipanel2` looks like a number.

Here's an example:

```
function testGUI
    fig = figure(1);
    panel = uipanel(fig);
    tbox = uicontrol('Style','text','String','hello','parent',panel);

    ch = get(panel,'Children')
    get(ch,'Type') 
    get(ch,'String')

end
```

It shows how to get the `Children` of the panel object with `ch = get(panel,'Children')` which should print something to console that looks like:

```
ch =

  182.0011
```

And to show you that this `ch` is in fact a handle to the static textbox that is a child of the panel, I've printed out the type and string of `ch` to console which should be the following:

```
ans =

uicontrol


ans =

hello
```

And here's an example of how to get the string in a textbox to update when you press a Push Button:

```
function testGUI
fig = figure(1);
panel = uipanel(fig);
tbox = uicontrol('Style','text','String','hello','parent',panel);
button = uicontrol('Style','PushButton','String','push me',...
    'Position',[100 100 50 25]);
set(button,'Callback',@mycallback)

function mycallback(src,eventdata)
    set(tbox,'String','updated')
end

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation. This was really helpful!